# java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) failing

Tags: java, comparison, output, comparison-operators

I have been trying to get an integer array and it keeps failing. I am trying to find the missing element in an array. Here is my code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GFG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int T,N,i,j=0,k=1;
        int C[]= new int[100];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        T=sc.nextInt();
        for(i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            N=sc.nextInt();
            for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                C[j]=sc.nextInt();

            }
            while(k<=N)
            {
                if(k==C[j])
                {
                    k++;
                    j++;

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(k);
                    k++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();

    }

}
```

I trying to find the missing element in a array of integers of consecutive natural numbers
Input:

```
1                //test cases
4               //array length              
1 2 3 5        // array elements
```

Desired Output:

```
4
```

But the output is

```
1  
2   
3   
4
```

The comparison is not executing. Why?

Comment: How exactly does it keep failing? If you get an error/exception you need to tell us what it is and show the stacktrace.

Comment: Lemme guess, you probably want to remove the quotes around `System.in`.

Comment: The comparison `if(k==C[j])` does not make any sense. C is an array of doubles, but k is an int. I am not sure what you are trying to do. But this is probably not the right way to do it.

Comment: In addition to the stacktrace please also indicate which line in your code the stacktriace says the exception comes from.

Comment: I got the error                                                                                
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at GFG.main(GFG.java:8)

Comment: I am trying to find the missing element in a integer array of consecutive natural numbers

Comment: After removing the double quotes the program runs without error

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my computer, with the input you mentioned, the program prints the numbers from 1 through 96 and then crashes with a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100` at the line `if(k==C[j])`.

There are a number of potential issues with your code. I’ll mention just two and leave it to yourself to see if you can find more.

1. After your loop `for(j=0;j<N;j++)` `j` is equal to `N` (4 in this case). You need to reset it to 0 before the next loop.
2. `k` never becomes 0, so your loop `while(k!=0)` runs forever, or more precisely, it runs off the bounds of your array, which causes the crash when you try to access the array element at index 100 (as you know, indices are 0 through 99). You need another way to stop the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer got the desired output.